# why should I use function instead of named lambdas in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, lambda, metaprogramming

Recently I've struggled a lot with function deduction and of course lambdas prove to be more flexible here, but doing so I've came to a question, why should I use function instead of named lambdas?

e.g.

```cpp
namespace
{
auto foo(auto && arg1, auto && arg2){
    return arg1 + arg2;
}

auto bar = [](auto&& arg1, auto && arg2){
    return arg1 + arg2;
}
}
```

`bar` is more flexible while doing templates and stuff, but is there any downsides using `bar`? performance or memory costs in real programming? I've run some tests with assembly output and bar proves to have even less instructions in some cases.

Comment: At least you type more with lamdas, lamdas are object often created at runtime. *some tests with assembly output and bar proves to have even less instructions in some cases* -- show us this case.

Comment: See this https://cppinsights.io/s/1c45ed0b

Comment: One difference is that you can't overload `bar`. There should not be any performance difference though.

Comment: there is ADL difference also.

Comment: @273K What?  no.  Stateless lambdas "take up 1 byte", but no runtime operation is done to create them.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont `auto bar` - this variable is created/initialized in runtime.

Comment: @273K That variable has 1 byte of size, which exists merely to guarantee a unique address, and no initialization code whatsoever (both in practice, and in theory as far as the C++ standard describes that situation).  No runtime operation occurs to create that lambda, except (barring as-if) a single byte of space may be reserved on the stack for it (but, if it address isn't taken, even that should be eliminated).  "Creating an object" in C++ is often something that doesn't occur outside of the formal machine C++ specifies: it reduces to a no-operation on the actual hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Functions support overloading, and support splitting declaration from implementation.

In addition, Functions participate in something called "argument dependent resolution".  Functions in the namespace of a class are searched for without the namespace being explicitly named on the line you call them.

```
namespace some_ns {
  struct some_struct {};
  void some_function( some_struct );
}
```

if you have

```
some_ns::some_struct bob;
some_function(bob);
```

then `some_ns::some_function` will be found  without `some_ns` being mentioned on the calling line.

You can get lambdas to participate in overload resolution using inheritance tricks, but even then it is a closed set of overloads.